# echo json_decode() returns only square brackets

Tags: php, sql, json

I'm trying to get a JSON object from a MySQL query, in order to add option elements in a select with JavaScript.

My PHP code is:

```
$carrera = $_GET['idcarrera'];

require_once("inc/config.php"); 
$pdo = conexionPDO();
$sql = "SELECT  materias.clave, materias.nombre FROM carreras_plan
            inner join carreras_plan_materia on carreras_plan.clave = carreras_plan_materia.clave_carrera
            inner join materias on carreras_plan_materia.clave_materia = materias.clave
            where carreras_plan_materia.clave_carrera like $carrera;";
    $ps = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $ps->execute();

    $data = $ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json_data = json_encode($data, true);
    echo $json_data;
```

If I get the JSON and use `console.log`, I get the query results in the console. Nevertheless, If I erase `echo $json_data;`, I get the next error when I try to parse the string to JSON:

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
> ```

I think that occurred because the `echo $json_data;` returns me only square brackets:

[image]

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: make sure $data variable is not empty before you do json_encode($data, true);
you can do it this way: print_r($data);

Comment: Is `$carrera` a string? Why aren't you binding the variable in your query? Do some basic error checking in your code.

Comment: Can you share the following output? print_r($json_data);

Comment: This will most likely not solve your issue, but the second parameter for `json_encode` are optional bitmask options and should be an integer value (`true` will be most likely casted to 1 though).

Comment: You're missing quotes around `$carrera` in the query string. If you were checking the query result you would have seen that it failed to execute.

Comment: @Nick I get the same result adding the quotes.

Comment: @Tschitsch Yeah, that detail not solve the problem, but thank you for your comment. I watched people using the parameter true, but I really don't understood why.

Comment: @Nohemi They most likely used it on `json_decode`, which would decode to array instead of object.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` without any wildcards? You might as well use `WHERE clave_carrera = ...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using prepared statements, and you should also be checking the results of your query. How do you know if it failed?

```
$carrera = $_GET['idcarrera'];

require_once("inc/config.php"); 
$pdo = conexionPDO();
$sql = "SELECT  materias.clave, materias.nombre FROM carreras_plan
        inner join carreras_plan_materia on carreras_plan.clave = carreras_plan_materia.clave_carrera
        inner join materias on carreras_plan_materia.clave_materia = materias.clave
        where carreras_plan_materia.clave_carrera like ?";
if ($ps = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
    if ($ps->execute([$carrera])) {
        $data = $ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        $data = ["error"=>"execute failed"];
    }
} else {
    $data = ["error"=>"prepare failed"]
}
$json_data = json_encode($data);
echo $json_data;
```

Comment: Where you are assigning the value `idcarrera` in the prepared statement? I get the error "execute failed", but i think is missing that assignment value.

Comment: Well you're using some custom database code so I can't know how it works. I did neglect to put the argument to `execute()` in an array, which would be a problem with the PDO client. Give it a try maybe.